# Computer hanging when booting Linux 5.4.2

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, compiling, crash

I have a laptop running Ubuntu and its bootloader is Grub2. I was using kernel version 5.3.0, but decided to switch to 5.4.2. I followed [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-and-installing-the-latest-linux-kernel-from-source-6d8df5345980/) guide to compile it from source. All went well, so I tried to boot it.

However, it froze after selecting it in the GRUB menu. After poking around a bit, I decided to try to boot it manually from the GRUB terminal. This showed that the `linux` command worked but the `initrd` command causes GRUB to freeze.

The system boots fine if I use kernel 5.3.0 again. Any ideas of why this occurs? I really want to get kernel 5.4.2 working.

System Info:

- OS: Ubuntu 19.10
- Architecture: x86_64
- Bootloader: GRUB2
- Boot Disk: EXT4 SSD
- Device: 80X4 Lenovo ideapad 320S-14IKB
- CPU: Intel i5-7200U

Comment: Mainline kernels are not supported on Ubuntu. You run them at your own risk. It is never guaranteed they would work.

Comment: And kernel 3.4 was never supposed to be run with Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: @Pilot6 I meant 5.4.2. Whoops!

Comment: 5.4.2 is not an Ubuntu kernel either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are compiling the kernel yourself, you are pretty much venturing on your own. You may receive assistance only from the few most technical savvy users among us.

Your system will probably run just fine if you revert to the supported kernel that comes with your Ubuntu distribution.